# Create ical with timezone using utc offset instead of time zone name

Tags: php, icalendar, utc

in my database i'm storing datetimes in UTC with additional column timezone offset as time zone instead of timezone name.

```
event_start         | event_end           | time_zone_offset

2017-12-25 10:00:00 | 2017-12-25 20:00:00 | +01:00
```

Now i need to create ics file using those values. Everywhere i was looking for solution they are using time zone names. Is it possible to use just utc offset instead of time zone name? And if it is possible, how?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use UTC time (using the UTC format described at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5 ) **as long as your event are not recurring**.

For recurring events, in most cases you want to use a local time + tzid as the absolute time of each instance will vary with daylight saving.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your dates already saved in UTC, I would just define them as UTC dates in ical too (trailing `Z`) and don't care about timezone infos.
The calendar app should automatically show the event in users current timezone

```
$event_start = "2017-12-25 10:00:00";
$timestamp = strtotime($event_start);
echo "DTSTART:" . date("Ymd\THis\Z", $timestamp); //DTSTART:20171225T100000Z
```

Comment: Also note for timezones that have daylight saving, the offset will be wrong half the year.  Better to use either UTC or the timezone city name (apps will adjust for daylight saving for that city)